# beberlei/DoctrineExtensions installation error

Tags: symfony

when I am going to install `beberlei/DoctrineExtensions` following error occurred.

I am working on Symfony 3.3. Please help me to sort out this issue I am using this extension because `YEAR` function is not working.

Is there any way to use `YEAR` function without using `beberlei/DoctrineExtensions`?

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install knpuniversity/guard-bundle 0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install knpuniversity/guard-bundle 0.2
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - Installation request for knpuniversity/guard-bundle ~0.1@dev -> satisfiable by knpuniversity/guard-bundle[0.2, 0.3, v0.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - knpuniversity/guard-bundle v0.1 requires symfony/security-bundle ~2.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/security-bundle[v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6
.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21
, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1,
v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.
5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.6.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.26|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.27|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.28|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.29|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.30|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.31|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.32|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.33|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.7.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.26|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.8.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony (locked at v3.3.5, required as 3.3.*) -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.3.5].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Answer (score 1):

You're issue is not related to `beberlei/DoctrineExtensions`, but `knpuniversity/guard-bundle`.

Your Symfony version is 3.3.5, which is incompatible with KnpUGuardBundle.

As mentioned on [KnpUGuardBundle GitHub page](https://github.com/knpuniversity/KnpUGuardBundle)

> This library is deprecated since Symfony 2.8 and won't work with Symfony 3.

Comment: so what can i do for Year() in symfony 3

Comment: You have an issue despite of your question about `DoctrineExtensions`. You have to solve it in first place anyway, because you won't be able to install or update anything. Then you should not have any trouble with installing `beberlei/DoctrineExtensions` or any other compatible package.